# AutoMapper in .NET MAUI iOS app in release build throws 'Attempting to JIT compile method xxx while running in aot-only mode' when mapping

Tags: azure-devops, automapper, maui

We use AutoMapper in Xamarin.Forms iOS projects and don't have any issues with Azure DevOps release builds, but when trying the same in .NET MAUI iOS we get the above error with a simple map:

```
var bla = mapper.Map<Class2>(new Class1());
```

This is with a release config build on Azure DevOps deployed to TestFlight. I haven't been able to replicate this locally at all.

Any suggestion or pointers? Is there anything I can do to force Automapper to not use reflection?

Comment: Probably https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79354. They'll include the fix in a service release.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I saw that issue but I don't think this is related. The example classes above don't have IEnumerable, and the error is different.

Comment: I'd bet it's the same. Anyway, AM has little to do with your error.

Comment: Have a try  to [enable Interpreter](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15681) and see if it works.

Comment: What kind of agent do you use to run pipeline Microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent? You can run it in self-hosted and see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, you must have the interpreter enabled to be able to use reflection. On Debug, the interpreter is enabled by default, that's why you cannot reproduce it locally. On release, it's disabled by default.

You can fix this by making sure the interpreter is enabled in both Debug and Release configs, by adding this to your `.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter> 
</PropertyGroup>
```